# Deploy on Widlfy from Jenkins with "Connection timed out" error

Tags: maven, jenkins, wildfly

I can deploy on wildfly local without any problems. But if i try to deploy from Jenkins remoting then I get the following exceptions:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:undeploy (default-cli) on project profiler-domain: Could not execute goal undeploy on `/opt/ci_cq/workspace/myapppackage/target/myapp.ear. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{`
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://myipOfRemotingServer:9990. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The port 9990 on wildfly is configured like this:

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/
>
```

And in the pom.xml I configured the wildfly plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <hostname>${hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${port}</port>
                    <username>${username}</username>
                    <password>${password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the `<inet-address/>` value for the management interface? Is it an accessible IP address? Is the firewall open to port 9990?

Comment: @James R.Perkins Hey, thank you! Your suggestion helps me! I didn't allow access from other IPs except Localhost:)

Answer (score 0):

As James R. Perkins said, i didn't allow any other adresses except localhost to access the management ports. After changing the  it works!